# Is the ring of functions of an elliptic curve a UFD?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, unique-factorization-domains, krull-dimension

Let $E$ be a nonsingular elliptic curve with ring of functions $k[E]$. Is $k[E]$ a unique factorization domain? I mean $E$ is a one-dimensional variety, so this should be right?

Comment: What does elliptic curve mean for you? Because the standard definition is a complete variety, which means it has no non constant regular functions, which makes the property of being a UFD rather trivial. (Generally, the correct connection is UFD and normal, not UFD and 1-dimensional - consider $V(xy)$, for instance.)

Comment: To me, an elliptic curve is a variety of the form $V(y^2-(x-a)(x-b)(x-c))$, with $a,b,c$ pairwise different. Or the homogenization thereof.

Comment: The choice of whether to take the affine version or the projective version matters a lot! The ring of global functions in the first case is a 1-dimensional normal ring (from the fact it's smooth), and thus a UFD, while in the second case the ring is just $k$ which is trivially a UFD.

Comment: @KReiser: why does 1-dim normal imply UFD? Certainly, Dedekind domains are 1-dim and normal, but are not generally UFDs. (I'm always a bit tentative about smooth vs. regular, but if $k[E]$ is regular, then it's at least locally a UFD by Auslander-Buchsbaum. Being a UFD is not a local property, though.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim oh no, I made a mistake! You're right, normal plus vanishing class group is equivalent to UFD, so normal does not always imply UFD. This is what I get for going too fast!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you take the affine or projective version of your definition in the comments. For instance, the affine curve cut out by $y^2=x^3-x$ has a ring of global functions which is not a UFD, but it's projective completion given by $y^2z=x^3-xz^2$ has ring of global functions just $k$, so it's trivially a UFD.